# Luxury Vinyl and noise

Tags: vinyl

We live in a first floor flat and planning to replace living area and hallway flooring using Vinyl. We already have vinyl in the Kitchen and the bathroom and found flooring is hard. As those areas are not always use by kids , we don't have any worries about noise . These areas are very small so hard to get an idea about noise.

Currently we have Carpets in living area and hallway where kids spend most of the time.We have young kinds and I wonder how Vinyl good in terms of noise?

Comment: you said that you already have vinyl in the kitchen ..... why don't you make your own observations? .... what is the point of even asking here?

Comment: Our Bathroom and Kitchen area are very small. So we're unable get good idea about noise. Hence asking the question.

Comment: get your kids to jump up and down in the kitchen

Comment: Noise is very subjective; it's going to be really hard for us to give you any sort of answer that matches your eventual experience.

Comment: The benefits of the vinyl will outweigh any problems with noise. Carpet in a high traffic area would get soiled and be very hard to clean. Change to vinyl and accept any increase in noise as a feature that celebrates the fact of children in the house.